# Steps required to add new language resource bundle in sap hybris Ecommerce.

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Steps required to add new language resource bundle in sap hybris Ecommerce. 
Steps required to add new language resource bundle in sap hybris Ecommerce. 
Steps required to add new language resource bundle in sap hybris Ecommerce. 
Steps required to add new language resource bundle in sap hybris Ecommerce. 
Steps required to add new language resource bundle in sap hybris Ecommerce.

Answer (score 1):

- Add lang.packs Property for the New Language
- Start Copying Localization Files
- Start the Server and Update Running System

Find more detail steps in [wiki](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/How+To+Add+New+Language+Translation+-+Tutorial) and refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47792621/2478134)

Answer (score 0):

Configure new language in backoffice. Use java locale language codes for new language. Make translation of i18 properties files. There are a lot of translation. You can ovverride translator bean for logging used words for decreasing translation need (all modules not used for every project).